# Finding non null value using single line of code c#

Tags: c#, null

I'm trying to find non null value from 3 strings using a single line code with some null checks in place.I'm getting NULL reference errors here as the c# is checking both sides of the "if" condition. How can I do this in a single line of code with all the null checks in place.

```
    string output = new String[] 
    {
        assessment.table1 == null ? "" : assessment.table1.Name, 
        assessment.table2 == null ? "" : assessment.table2.Name, 
        assessment.table3 == null ? "" : assessment.table3.Name 
    }
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s != "").ToString() ?? null
```

Open to other approaches to achieve this as well.

Comment: *"the c# is checking both sides of the "if" condition"* - Can you elaborate on that?  How specifically does this fail?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: So when assessment.table1 is null, c# is still checking for assessment.table1.Name instead of just setting that as an empty string.

Comment: `var result = assessment.table1?.Name ?? assessment.table2?.Name ?? assessment.table3?.Name;`

Comment: @VPP: No, it's not. That's just not how the conditional ?: operator works. Please try to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that, and I suspect you'll have trouble doing so. (Dmitry's approach is what I'd use, but it's important to correct your understanding of how the operator works too.)

Comment: This is my assumption: all three tables are null, so all the array elements are empty strings. So, `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` (the default for the `String`). And then you try to call `null.ToString()` and that throws.

Comment: @VPP: *"when assessment.table1 is null, c# is still checking for assessment.table1.Name"* - [This doesn't happen when I test it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qmjeG5).

Comment: @David "How specifically does this fail?" either `assessment` is null meaning NRE throws upon array init, or a `.Name` is null (or all Names are not empty) and FirstOrDefault returns null and attempting to call .ToString throws

Comment: @HasBeanCounter: Possibly, or something not shown here could fail as well.  The OP is operating on a false assumption and needs to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `assessment` *can't be* `null`, but any `table` *can* we can put

```
assessment.tableN?.Name
```

to get either `Name` value or `null` if `tableN`. Then we can combine all three expresssions for `table1` .. `table3` into one with a help of `??`

```
var output = assessment.table1?.Name
          ?? assessment.table2?.Name
          ?? assessment.table3?.Name;
```

If you want to get empty string if all tables are `null` add one `??` more:

```
var output = assessment.table1?.Name
          ?? assessment.table2?.Name
          ?? assessment.table3?.Name 
          ?? "";
```

Comment: And if assessment can be null, and you don't want to detect that specifically over any other case, `?.` can be used to access `tableN` too